# Transparent images in wxPython {Mask}

Tags: python, image, wxpython, transparency

I'm tired of searching this on the net and i cant get it to work. I need to turn green pixels into transparent ones, no half transparency needed. Wondering how can effectively use a mask, but the wx docs doesn't help much really...

Hope someone can give me a tip, regards.

Related code

```
png = wx.Image('sun2.png', wx.BITMAP_TYPE_PNG).ConvertToBitmap()
#print png.HasMask() fail
png.SetMaskColour((0,255,0))
#mask=wx.Mask(png,wx.Colour(0,255,0))
#png.SetMask(mask)
imge=wx.StaticBitmap(self, -1, png, (10, 5), (png.GetWidth(), png.GetHeight()))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check the [wxpython docs and demo](http://www.wxpython.org/download.php#stable).
In the demo **Mask** they show a method to use a transparent mask:

```
    # Now we'll create a mask in a bit of an easier way, by picking a
    # colour in the image that is to be the transparent colour.
    self.bmp_withcolourmask  = images.TestStar2.GetBitmap()
    mask = wx.Mask(self.bmp_withcolourmask, wx.WHITE)
    self.bmp_withcolourmask.SetMask(mask)
```