# wx.StaticBitmap - simple transparency (mask, png, bmp?)

Tags: python, python-2.7, wxpython, png

After 1 week of constant failure I'm still not able to do a simple task: Load a png with alpha channel or with white background (in example bellow) and have it maintain its transparency in wx.StaticBitmap.

This I need in a wx.panel later. It should stay like this or similar.

This is one of my approaches (white background):

```
def __init__(self, parent):
    wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
    self.loc = wx.Image("intro/image.png",wx.BITMAP_TYPE_PNG).ConvertToBitmap()
    z = wx.Mask(self.loc, wx.WHITE) 
    self.loc.SetMask(z) 
    self.locopic = wx.StaticBitmap(self, -1, self.loc, (0, 0))
```

I read tons on this topic. I'm rubbish. Sorry. I think I miss something obvious here. [wx.Mask](http://wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.Mask-class.html) , [Transparent images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12029960/transparent-images-in-wxpython-mask)

Update:

I managed to get this far with the example found [at WorkinWithImages](http://wiki.wxpython.org/index.cgi/WorkingWithImages):

```
import ImageConversions
...

    puFilename = "intro/imagealpha.png"
    pilImage = Image.open( puFilename )
    pilImageWithAlpha = ImageConversions.WxImageFromPilImage( pilImage, createAlpha=True )
    self.puWxBitmap = pilImageWithAlpha.ConvertToBitmap()
    self.locopic = wx.StaticBitmap(self, -1, self.puWxBitmap)
```

This is creating the transparent wx.image from a PNG with alpha channel BUT in wx.StaticBitmap would have an ugly black colour where the transparency should be. This is driving me maaad!!! HELP PLEASE!

If only I would manage to display in the wx.panel that image with the transparency in the right place
Thank you community!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As discussed in the python SO chat:

```
class MyPanel(wx.Panel):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.OnPaint)

        self.loc = wx.Bitmap("intro/image.png")

    def OnPaint(self, evt):
        dc = wx.PaintDC(self)
        dc.SetBackground(wx.Brush("WHITE"))

        # ... drawing here all other images in order of overlapping
        dc.DrawBitmap(self.loc, 0, 0, True)
```

The trick is to draw all overlapping images with the `wx.PaintDC`.

Additionally it's more convenient to use `wx.Bitmap` instead of `wx.Image(..., wx.BITMAP_TYPE_PNG).ConvertToBitmap()` for loading PNGs from the file system.

Comment: I'm very grateful that you spent your time and found the solution that I did understand and implement succesfully! Thank you!

Comment: I get this error: `wx._core.wxAssertionError: C++ assertion "IsOk()" failed at /tmp/pip-build-neujnbmg/wxPython/ext/wxWidgets/src/common/dcgraph.cpp(437) in SetTextBackground(): wxGCDC(cg)::SetTextBackground - invalid DC` ☹